# JQuery And Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

I'm getting a problem with Jquery and Checkboxes.
For example, I've got this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="guest" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="guest" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="guest" value="3" />

<input type="text" id="player-1" />
<input type="text" id="player-2" />
<input type="text" id="player-3" />
```

My question, and what I've been searching, is how to disable an input[type=text] with JQuery.

This is my code:

```
<script>
$("input").on("click", function() {
var i = $("input:checked").val();
if(this.checked)
$("#player-"+i).attr("disabled", "disabled");
else
$("#player-"+i).removeAttr("disabled");
});
</script>
```

May there's something wrong I don't get, but when i click a checkbox, it disable the first text, if I decheck it, nothing happends until I check one of the other one.

Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
 var i = $(this).val();
```

Instead of

```
var i = $("input:checked").val();
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YVJvX/1/)

```
$("input").on("click", function () {
    var i = $(this).val();
    if (this.checked) $("#player-" + i).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else $("#player-" + i).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I used var i as you commented, and works. Also I applied part of the code from user undefined, and worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable your inputs with the [jQuery `prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

for your example:

```
$("#player-" + i).prop('disabled', this.checked);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, next time I'll use that function of prop()!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$("input:checked").val()` in this line.

Change this to,

```
$("input").on("click", function () {
    var i = $(this).val();
    if (this.checked) 
        $("#player-" + i).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else 
        $("#player-" + i).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Because it gets value only if it is checked. When you uncheck the checkbox, it will show **undefined**.

Comment: Yes, it was giving me undefined when i dechecked it. Thanks to all of you, now it's working =)